# Changing text layout in a UILabel - Specifically where it starts from

Tags: iphone, ios, text, interface-builder, uilabel

I have this problem with one of my UILabels, I would like to have the text that it displays begin being drawn at the top left of the label rather than the middle left.

Current screen:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see the word "Description" in the label appears in the centre and to the left of the label.  I would like it to start at the top-left instead.  How do I implement this either programatically or in IB?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: I don't think there's a setting to adjust the vertical placement of the text.  There might be tricks you can do by making it a multi-line label and using some sort of "non-printing" character code to space out your label text.  Otherwise you either need to adjust the height of your label or place another, properly sized, label over the top of it -- programatically you'd create a new UILabel, size it horizontally to the width of the existing label, size it vertically for one text line, set origin to 0,0, then addSubview to the existing label.

Comment: It occurs to me, though, that you may want to be using a UITextView instead of a label.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, changing to use the UITextView helped a lot.  A bit of messing around in IB get me close enough to the layout I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Description label to a UITextView pretty much solved my problem.  It allowed for multiple lines of text and was much simpler to implement.  Also looked a little prettier.

Thanks for your help, particularly Daniel.

Jack

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that you're eventually going to put a description in, in which case it would be easier in the long run to simply make the UILabel for "Description" one line high, and put it at the top. Then, just add another multiline UILabel for the actual content. Having separate UILabels will make things simpler later.